# get each id in the div tag

Tags: jquery, html

```
var data = "<div><table width='100%'><tr><td align='right' ><div class='close16'/></td></tr></table><div><table><tr><td rowspan='4' width='50px;'><img src='" + staffItem.Photo + "' Width='48' Height='48'  /></td><td>" + staffItem.Name + " ( " + staffItem.StaffId + " )</td></tr><tr><td><table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'><tr><td>" + staffItem.Email + "</td><td>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</td><td>" + staffItem.Mobile + "</td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></div></div> ";
$('#staffInCharge').append(data);
```

I've collected staff details like this, from the autocomplete textbox, and am storing these into a div.....how can I collect the "staffId" alone(even if I have 5 or 10 records within the div).....I think I can get it by using .each method, I donno how to proceed, can anyone help me here

Comment: am getting it from database, actually it displays perfectly in the div, I need to get the staffId alone for each and every staff within my div

Comment: Please format your HTML so it's actually readable. That generally means indented and one tag per line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to wrap the id in a span, or something where you could easily target it with jQuery.

For brevity, I just pulled the column with the id:

```
... "<td>" + staffItem.Name + " ( <span class='id'>" + staffItem.StaffId + "</span> )</td> "...
```

And then get them with jQuery:

```
function getIds() {
    var ids = [];
    $(".id").each(function() {
      ids.push($(this).text());
    });
    return ids;
}
```

Now anywhere, you can use `getIds()` to get the list of ids.

```
var myListOfIds = getIds(); // returns [50, 51, ...]
```

Comment: thanks jeremyharris for ur response.....i still dont understand how to get StaffIds' specifically......can u give some more idea

Comment: I collected the StaffId in the span as 

var array = jQuery.makeArray($("#staffInCharge").find("span"));

here I can see the StaffIds' of all the staffs in the div, but when I put the breakpoint there it shows the StaffId as InnerHTML.......how can I read it....

Comment: I updated my answer to include it. Since you're iterating through the spans you can just get the ids with `html()` or `text()`.

Comment: when I execute this code for the first record, the staffId is storing perfectly(ex: 50), but when I adding the 2nd record the first id is coming twice(ex:50,50,51).....whats the issue?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the html. Use `console.log()` to log some of the divs, the ids, etc. Are you calling it more than once? Because maybe your `ids` JS var is global and you just add to it again.

Comment: u r great geremy, actually i just tried to push the ids into a globally declared array, now I corrected it......actually I want to get the values in the array "ids" in someother function, how can I do that, and y do we use console.log

Comment: To get them in some other function, wrap the code that gets them in a function and call it from the other one. `console.log()` is a way of logging output to a javascript debugger, like Firebug, Chrome's dev tools, or MS's dev tools. Be careful though because not all browsers have it and will throw an error.

Comment: can u explain getting the values from some other function, with some code example please

Comment: Yeah sure why not (edited answer). Any further questions should be directed to a chat or asked as another question. The questions you're asking now are no longer related to your original post. Please accept the answer and jump in a chat to ask any other basic JS questions you have.

Comment: you r really great jeremy, for me its working perfectly, i dont have enough reputation to come chat, thanksssss alot